# Python Unit Testing: How is function automatically called without providing function name?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am looking into the codes in vanilla_vae [here](https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE/blob/master/models/vanilla_vae.py) and its unit test test_vae [here](https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE/blob/master/tests/test_vae.py).

In the code snippet of test_vae below, I am confused as to how **self.model(x)** portion in **test_loss(self)** function directly calls VanillaVAE class's forward method without mentioning the function name. Could anyone provide me insight on this?

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    # self.model2 = VAE(3, 10)
    self.model = VanillaVAE(3, 10)

def test_loss(self):
    x = torch.randn(16, 3, 64, 64)

    result = self.model(x)
    loss = self.model.loss_function(*result, M_N = 0.005)
    print(loss)
```

Comment: You'd have to check the definition of `self.model`.

Comment: Why do you think `VanillaVAE.forward` gets called?

Comment: self.model is an instance of VanillaVAE with params 3 and 10 which are input channels and latent dimensions respectively. @matszwecja

Comment: @Joooeey I followed the print statements I added in the code and also how *result is accessed within the loss_function clarifies it.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `vanilla_vae` inherits from [BaseVAE](https://github.com/AntixK/PyTorch-VAE/blob/a6896b944c918dd7030e7d795a8c13e5c6345ec7/models/base.py), which inherits from [nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module).

nn.Module contains a `__call__` method, which is a built in method that makes classes callable.

This calls `_call_impl` where the forward function is referenced.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is clear to me now. @Lucibus

Comment: I looked for the `__call__()` method but couldn't find it. Do you have a line no.?

Comment: The statement is = "`__call`__ : Callable[..., Any] = _call_impl" .

Answer (score 0):

This behavior depends on the [torch.nn.Module](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html). That is the PyTorch base class for creating neural networks. In the **forward** function, you define how your model is going to be run, from input to output.

This means that every time you pass an input to your model, the forward function is called automatically and it returns what it is defined. In this case, as I can see from your link, a List[Tensor]:

```
 def forward(self, input: Tensor, **kwargs) -> List[Tensor]:
        mu, log_var = self.encode(input)
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, log_var)
        return  [self.decode(z), input, mu, log_var]
```

[Here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/nnft_tutorial.html) you can also find a couple of examples on how the nn package is used from PyTorch.